# Textarea Scrollbar not showing in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, textarea, scrollbar

I have a textarea which is dynamically create/inserted into the DOM. If the text area is below 75px height and the text inside of it exceeds that then you would expect a scroll bar however you don't see it.

Any other textarea that is larger than 75px will show the scroll bar properly.

Is there a way to fix this, or is that just a Firefox default behavior?

Here is my CSS

```
textarea {
           position:absolute; 
           border:0;  
           overflow:auto; 
           resize:none;
}
```

UPDATED: The behavior is now not consistent, now it goes down to 60px below 60px no scrollbar

Comment: What happens as you add content that goes below the bottom of the texarea?

Comment: you have to use arrow keys to get to it

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with height smaller than 75px. However, when the height of textarea is very small (about 35px) scrollbar won't fit and is therefore not displayed. Try adding following CSS for the textarea:

```
textarea {    
    resize: none; //disable resizing, so that the scrollbar is 100% high
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Firefox and Internet Explorer simply do not support any CSS styling of the scrollbar. Using a plugin really is your only option